# AWS Application Load Balancer (ALB) passing requests to lambda with body base64 encoded?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have an AWS ALB with SSL turned on.  When I try to access the web page, the ALB calls a lambda function with form data.  When not configured to run SSL, everything works fine.  But, with SSL, the body shows up base64 encoded.  I could just decode it and use it, except that it doesn't decode to a useful format (see below).  How do I get the form data is a useful format? (IE: json)

Thanks

base64 encoded body:

```
LS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLTk2OTM2MjQ3MTIzNDE5MTIwOTQ1MDE3Ng0KQ29udGVudC1EaXNwb3NpdGlvbjogZm9ybS1kYXRhOyBuYW1lPSJmaXJzdE5hbWUiDQoNCkZyZWQNCi0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS05NjkzNjI0NzEyMzQxOTEyMDk0NTAxNzYNCkNvbnRlbnQtRGlzcG9zaXRpb246IGZvcm0tZGF0YTsgbmFtZT0ibGFzdE5hbWUiDQoNCkZsaW5zdG9uZQ0KLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLTk2OTM2MjQ3MTIzNDE5MTIwOTQ1MDE3Ni0tDQo=
```

decoded body:

```
b'----------------------------969362471234191209450176\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="firstName"\r\n\r\nFred\r\n----------------------------969362471234191209450176\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="lastName"\r\n\r\nFlinstone\r\n----------------------------969362471234191209450176--\r\n'
```

Comment: What does the request to the ALB look like? The request body should contain the data in JSON format..

Comment: curl --location --request POST 'https://www.---.com' \
--form 'firstName=Fred' \
--form 'lastName=Flinstone'

Comment: Yeah, I'm guessing the ALB would only correctly base64 encode JSON data. Try posting JSON data in the body of the request with curl.

Answer (score 0):

So in the example above, the ALB is encoding everything correctly. It's showing you exactly what curl is sending over.

When you use the `curl --form` option, what you get is `Content-Type: multipart/form-data boundary=<divider string>`. You can see this if you check the request header. Here's a sample of what that information looks like.

```
--------------------------b788e21bda17cfad Content-Disposition: form-data; name="firstName"

Fred
--------------------------b788e21bda17cfad Content-Disposition: form-data; name="lastName"

Smith
--------------------------b788e21bda17cfad--
```

I assume you're expecting the more common `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type. To get that, use
`curl -X POST -d "firstName=Fred" -d "lastName=Smith" <URL>`, which would result in the more familiar body content:

> `first=Fred&lastName=Smith`

Finally to post your request as JSON, use:

> `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"firstName": "Fred","lastName": "Smith"}' <URL>`

As a final note: Strangely enough, when you send JSON through ALB, even with SSL enabled, it doesn't base64-encode the body. Just remember to set the content type correctly so that the ALB knows you're sending JSON.